# Win7/Python3.3: PyLint failed to load its plugins

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

Good evening! I have installed pylint on python 3.3 and got following problem: at initialization step pylint fails to load plugin modules (from package `pylint.checkers`). Thanks to debuging I found that problem is in the comand

```
module = __import__(basename, globals(), globals(), None)
```

which is executed from `__init__.py` of the `checkers` package. `basename` is correct name of module (file) inside this package but without extension (I have checked this). However ImportError exception is raised. I culdn't step into `__import__` function so I don't know what is exact reason of the exception. Is there any way to find out if it is bug of new version of python, incompatibility of pylint and new version of python or my fault (may be in configuring of python or installing of pylint)? My OS is Windows 7.

P.S. Sorry for my weak English. It isn't my native language.

Comment: How have you managed to install the `logilab-astng` dependency? I always get errors when installing it. Is it necessary to run `2to3` on it prior to installation?

Comment: I simply execute `full_path_to_python_interpreter setup.py install` in `logilab-astng` source code folder. There isn't any problem.

Comment: I always assumed that the errors for the tests when installing `logilab-astng` had some deeper meaning, but you are correct that they don't seem to affect the installation and running of the package or of pylint. Thanks for the information, I was being silly and not running pylint on Python 3.x just because of that.

Comment: And I have just installed Python 3.2 and pylint works excellent. So it seems to be some incompatibility of Python 3.3 and pylint.

Answer (score 1):

As of 0.26, Python 3.3 is not supported by Pylint. Logilab mainly works with Python 2.x and so help with the most recent 3.x versions is deeply appreciated.

You should approach the team on the python-projects@lists.logilab.org mailing list to discuss this.